# Calculating a backwards index for a Swift collection that wraps two other sorted collections

Tags: swift, collections, bidirectional

I've taken on someone else's quest to create a sequence that wraps a given sorted sequence and filters out the elements belonging to a second given sorted sequence, and the predicate used for sorting is given too.  I've written eager and lazy versions.  The lazy version supports `Collection` if both the main and filter sequences are also collections.

```
public struct LazyPresortedSubtractionSequence<Base: Sequence, Filter: Sequence> where Base.Element == Filter.Element {
    /// The sequence where the vended elements come from.
    var base: Base
    /// The sequence where matches to be filtered come from.
    var filters: Filter
    /// The closure for determining the relative order of elements.
    let areInIncreasingOrder: (Base.Element, Base.Element) -> Bool
    /// Creates a sequence vending elements of a given base sequence minus the elements that are also in another sequence.
    init(_ base: Base, filter: Filter, by areInIncreasingOrder: @escaping (Base.Element, Base.Element) -> Bool) {
        self.base = base
        filters = filter
        self.areInIncreasingOrder = areInIncreasingOrder
    }
}

//...

public typealias LazyPresortedSubtractionCollection<Base: Collection, Filter: Collection> = LazyPresortedSubtractionSequence<Base, Filter> where Base.Element == Filter.Element

extension LazyPresortedSubtractionCollection: Collection {
    public struct Index: Comparable {
        /// The targeted element in the base collection.
        public let index: Base.Index
        /// The next unused filter element when the target element is chosen.  Meant to be a cache to calculate the next index, not significant for direct use.
        let filterIndex: Filter.Index
        public static func == (lhs: Index, rhs: Index) -> Bool {
            return lhs.index == rhs.index
        }
        public static func < (lhs: Index, rhs: Index) -> Bool {
            return lhs.index < rhs.index
        }
    }

    /// Find the first element of `base`'s suffix to not be filtered out by elements in `filter`'s suffix, without using loops.
    private func nextIndex(baseStart: Base.Index, filterStart: Filter.Index) -> Index {
        guard baseStart < base.endIndex, filterStart < filters.endIndex, !areInIncreasingOrder(base[baseStart], filters[filterStart]) else {
            return Index(index: baseStart, filterIndex: filterStart)
        }

        let incrementBase = !areInIncreasingOrder(filters[filterStart], base[baseStart])
        let nextBaseIndex = base.index(baseStart, offsetBy: incrementBase ? +1 : 0)
        return nextIndex(baseStart: nextBaseIndex, filterStart: filters.index(after: filterStart))
    }

    /**
     The position of the first element in a nonempty collection.

     If the collection is empty, `startIndex` is equal to `endIndex`.

     - Warning: Since the collection filters elements and can't cache the result (since the properties involved are conditional), the computation is linear instead of constant.

     - Complexity: O(_n_ + _k_), where *n* is the element count of the wrapped collection and *k* is the element count of the filter collection.
     */
    public var startIndex: Index {
        return nextIndex(baseStart: base.startIndex, filterStart: filters.startIndex)
    }
    public var endIndex: Index {
        // The value for `filterIndex` may be wrong for some collections, but it's not used in comparisons.
        // (By wrong, I mean `index(after: indices.last).filterIndex` may be before `filters.endIndex`.  This may happen when `base.last` is less than `filters.last`.)
        return Index(index: base.endIndex, filterIndex: filters.endIndex)
    }
    public subscript(position: Index) -> Base.Element {
        return base[position.index]
    }
    public func index(after i: Index) -> Index {
        return nextIndex(baseStart: base.index(after: i.index), filterStart: i.filterIndex)
    }
}
```

Now I want to make it reversible if the two inner collections are reversible.

```
extension LazyPresortedSubtractionCollection: BidirectionalCollection where Base: BidirectionalCollection, Filter: BidirectionalCollection {
    public func index(before i: Index) -> Index {
        // What goes here?
    }
}
```

When you go before the indexed element, you need to seek out how many duplicate values exist in both inner collections and include the previous only if the main collection has more than the filter collection, otherwise move on.  It's getting hard for me to wrap my head around this one, at least the part I have to synchronize the filter collection indexes with main collection indexes, but backwards!  Is this even possible?  Remember that both inner collections are already sorted with respect to the also-stored ordering predicate.